# Max average value for a time period

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query on a database table in MySQL. I am trying to figure out the maximum average value of watts for a time period of consecutive seconds. So, for example, I have a table (picture provided) and I want to query the table to find the largest average watts for 60 consecutive seconds that exists in the table for a particular person. I am attaching a picture of the table so you can see the data structure. Many thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Here is what I have tried, but can't figure out the consecutive time piece.

```
select max(avg_watts)
from 
(
  SELECT AVG(watts) avg_watts FROM tblworkoutdata GROUP BY personid
) tmp
```

[screenshot of db table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/For0X.png)

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not as easy as it seems. Say you have this data:

```
minute   watts
1        100
59       200
60       300
70       300
80       500
120      100
```

This gives the following 60 consecutive minutes ranges:

```
minute   avg watts
1-60     150
59-80    325
70-120   300
```

But why what rule find these ranges? I'd use the following algorithm:

1. For each minute in the table find the maximum minute still in the same range (1->60, 59->80, 60->80, 70->120, 80->120, 120->120).
2. From these pairs take the minimum start minute per end minute (1<-59, 59<-80, 70<-120)

Then

3. For each of these ranges find the average watts
4. From these avarages take the maximum

The query:

```
select max(avg_watts)
from
(
  select
    (
      select avg(watts)
      from tblworkoutdata data 
      where data.time between groups.t1 and groups.t2
    ) as avg_watts
  from
  (
    select min(t1) as t1, t2
    from
    (
      select
        time as t1,
        (
          select max(tbl2.time)
          from tblworkoutdata tbl2
          where tbl2.time between tbl1.time and tbl1.time + 59
        ) as t2
      from tblworkoutdata tbl1
    ) pairs
    group by t2
  ) groups
) averages;
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/OZT99379

You can of course move subqueries from `SELECT` clauses to `FROM` clauses if you like this better.

(It's easy to get this result per person. Just include the person ID everywhere and group your results by it.)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this tomorrow and if it works, I'll update accordingly. Thank you for your patience. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score -2):

You'd need to join the data-table to itself using whatever column contains the date times. Something like:

```
SELECT MAX(avg_watts) FROM (
    SELECT i.date_time,
           AVG(i2.watts) AS avg_watts
    FROM tblworkoutdata i
    JOIN tblworkoutdata i2
         ON  i2.date_time >= i.date_time 
         AND i2.date_time <  DATE_ADD(i.date_time, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
    GROUP BY i.date_time 
)
```

Comment: This query does not group by `personid`

Comment: @IVOGELOV It's meant to be an example of how you could get a moving average over a time frame. I don't know the specifics of this guy's data model.

Comment: Okay, but then how `1/60/24` which is 0.000694 means `1 minute` ?

Comment: Good point, I was using Oracle syntax, updated for mySQL syntax

Comment: Thank you. The time column is not a date_time column and is just a record of time elapsed in the workout. So the column values would go 1,2,3,4,5,etc. Does that change things? You can see the data structure in the screenshot I uploaded. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Sure, just adopt it to use your values instead of a date_time. Think of it this way: For each record, you're getting the average of all records that fall within the next 60 seconds (ie, joining the table to itself). Then, you just get the maximum of all those averages. As a side note, you'll get better answers if you copy your data into your actual question, instead of giving a screenshot.